# Update schema table data into another schema table

Tags: postgresql

I have a function having input parameters inserting data into `xch.xch_transmas_patient` table after inserting data into `xch.xch_transmas_patient` table I am trying to update data into `lt_transmas_patient` table by writing update statement and I have written my code in func like this is this correct or not

```
UPDATE lt_transmas_patient p 

        SET patient_first_name=pa.patient_first_name,
        patient_last_name=pa.patient_last_name,
        patient_birthdate=pa.patient_birthdate,
        patient_email=pa.patient_email,
        patient_mobile=pa.patient_mobile,
        patient_home_phone=pa.patient_home_phone,
        patient_updated_by=pa.patient_created_by,
        patient_updated_on=pa.patient_updated_on,
        patient_salutation=pa.patient_salutation,
        patient_maritalstatus=pa.patient_maritalstatus,
        patient_education_level=pa.patient_education_level,
        patient_blood_group=pa.patient_blood_group,
        patient_mother_tongue=pa.patient_mother_tongue,
        patient_identification_mark=pa.patient_identification_mark

        FROM xch.xch_transmas_patient pa
        join xch.xch_transmasmap_mpi_link m on m.mpi_lk_xch_mpi=pa.patient_mpi and m.mpi_lk_partner_id=2
        where p.patient_mpi=m.mpi_lk_external_mpi
        and pa.patient_mpi=_patient_mpi;
```

Comment: `is this correct or not` ... _you_ tell _us_ this by letting us know whether or not the query worked without error.  Yes, it actually looks correct to me.

Comment: yah its working fine without error but is there any improper syntax in it

Comment: iam not sure abt this syntax of update data in to 1 schema table from another schema table and using a common table with join in which both table mpi's r present

Comment: The structure looks correct, not sure about cross schema queries but I would guess it should work.